# Checkmark disappearing from select all on SSRS

Tags: reporting-services

I have a report with 10 parameters, of which 7 are multi-select via a query. One of the parameters (only one that I have seen) has a weird issue where I'll select all in that parameter then continue selecting the other parameters. When I go back to that parameter, there are some that are no longer selected.

I select all

[image: Select All]

I go into another parameter and edit that, go back and I see this.

[image: Go back to view again]

Here is a sample of the data that is being pulled. There isn't any NULLS.

[image: Data being pulled]

While I do have queries that drive these dropdowns, there aren't any cascading selects where it could add/remove items from the list.

Has anyone come across this? Where should I start investigating?

Update: This seems to happen both in IE and Chrome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When this has happened to me in the past, it has been because the value from the dataset query is NULL where the label is 'SALARIED POLICE...'. Perhaps you need to try using an ISNULL in the dataset query to replace this value?

EDIT: It is also possible that SSRS is only checking each distinct value once, so any duplicates are being unchecked.

Comment: There isn't any nulls. I just added a screenshot of the raw data.

Comment: Ah. I suspect, then, that it is the fact that the value is duplicated that is causing your issue.

Comment: OMG! I didn't notice that! Thanks!